# Does a modern JVM optimize simple inline anonymous class allocation?

Tags: java, optimization, jvm

I got a code review remark today to extract this anonymous class into a field, to avoid allocating it over and over again:

```
Collections.transform(new Function<Foo, Bar>(){
  Bar apply(Foo foo) {
    // do some simple local transform of foo into a Bar.
  }
});
```

I replied that "it doesn't matter, the JVM optimizes it". While I know for a fact that this "optimization" won't affect the performance in any way and I think the added value of having the code accessible inline is worth it, I'm curious if I was right about the JVM optimization.
So, my question is - it the proposed refactoring **absolutely a no-op**, because the JVM will optimize it anyway, or is there some minuscule theoretical perf gain here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wouldn't particularly *expect* it to optimize that, no.

It would have to make sure that `Collections.transform` never stashed away the `Function`, and that the method itself never makes `this` visible etc. Obviously all that's doable - but it would potentially be quite a lot of work for a relatively small gain in a very few situations.

Now what any particular VM does is hard to say without very careful examination - but I think "It's not going to affect performance significantly" is a more reasonable thing to say than "The JVM optimizes it."

Comment: Figured as much. I place too much faith sometimes in the magical powers of optimizers.

Answer (score 1):

Whether you extract it into a field or not should really depend on how frequently you call it and how long the parent class lasts. If the parent class lives as long as the app and you call this thing once in a blue moon, why bother holding onto an instance for such a trivial operation? Conversely if you call this thing frequently, then yes hold it in a variable to save the bother of creating multiple objects.

I think my own rule of thumb is if the scope of the inner class is within the method call and your method is not performance critical and the implementation is small, just leave it where it is.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the JVM would optimize it- likely, the performance hit isn't worth the cost to optimize. However, the huge benefits to the code being inline vastly outweigh it.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to inline code and not creating an object for the Function each time, why not use a loop. You won't get more efficient than that.  However, if you want readability rather than performance (and most of the time this is a better idea) you may find functional notation suites you.

```
List<Bar> bars = new ArrayList<Bar>();
for(Foo foo: foos) {
   // do some simple local transform of foo into a Bar.
   bars.add(bar);
}
```

Personally, I find that simpler.