# Will the JVM ever inline an object's instance variables and methods?

Tags: java, scala, jvm, jit, jvm-hotspot

Suppose I have a very tight inner loop, each iteration of which accesses and mutates a single bookkeeping object that stores some simple data about the algorithm and has simple logic for manipulating it

The bookkeeping object is private and final and all of its methods are private, final and @inline. Here's an example (in Scala syntax):

```
object Frobnicate {
  private class DataRemaining(val start: Int, val end: Int) {
    @inline private def nextChunk = ....
  }

  def frobnicate {
    // ...
    val bookkeeper = new DataRemaining(0, 1000)
    while( bookeeper.hasData ) {
      val data = bookkeeper.nextChunk
      // ......
    }
  }
 }
```

Will the JVM ever inline the whole DataRemaining object into `Frobnicate.frobnicate`? That is, will it treat `start` and `end` as local variables and inline the nextChunk code directly into `frobnicate`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java it can inline fields and methods in a situation as you have.  It does not eliminate the Object completely, but gets close.  I assume Scala would work similarly.

Comment: Since this is done by the JIT compiler of the JVM, the language doesn't matter. So yes, it does inline these methods.

Comment: @Kim, The only reason I am not sure it how Scala converts the code into byte code. If it efficient (and it should be) there is no problem.  If its more dynamic than it would appear, it may confuse the JIT.

Comment: Scala is not a "dynamic" language, at least not in the sense of needing a Map lookup for every method call...

Comment: I guess one issue is that Scala val's and var's are implemented as virtual methods - so that might limit whether or not the JVM can inline them.

Comment: @Bill, The JVM can inline "virtual" methods if it can determine that one or two of them are used most (and they are short)

Comment: Would inlining anyhow change if the DataRemaining class was not private? I am just thinking about effectiveness of a Decorator pattern.

Comment: @user271996 the JVM optimises based on local usage.  This means if you only use one class in an expression, the fact it could have been many classes doesn't make much difference to performance.

Comment: What is then the difference between this case with public and the case described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115783/does-a-modern-jvm-optimize-simple-inline-anonymous-class-allocation ?

Comment: @user271996 in the example above the object is allocated outside the loop. If you create an object inside the loop, it doesn't optimise it away.