# Is there an API / Tool that implements "user-definable value types" in the JVM?

Tags: java, inline

If I have a simple data type, something that could be represented by a single primitive value, like an int, for example a counter, and my class is immutable (this is important), I would like to define all the business logic, including preconditions like "cannot be negative" so that it's usage is safe, and it can only ever contain valid data. With types like that, you can't accidentally add the number of wheels to the number of passengers (if they are *different* counter types), but you could if both were just ints.

So what I would like is a way to annotate those types as "inlineable", so that the references of an instance would be replaced to the value of the state, and calls to instance methods would be replaced with calls to static methods taking or receiving the state, which the JIT could inline too. One limitation being that not all use-sites could be replaced, like putting one of those in a Java List. But arrays could be replaced efficiently.

So the main benefit would be to "remove the object overhead", and indirectly the object creation and GC cost, while keeping your code as safe as possible.

The JIT does method inlining for us, and that is alright in most cases, but it does not (until now at least) remove the object overhead, which is why the state of objects is usually made of with primitive types, instead of business-model specific types. Business-model specific types are safer to use, and follow the DRY principle; you only have to define your preconditions once. But the price you have to pay for such simple is simply to high in many case.

Ideally I would prefer a byte-code level tool, compile time or load-time, because I'm doing mixed Java-Scala coding.

I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215138/will-the-jvm-ever-inline-an-objects-instance-variables-and-methods) which is related, the poster wants to know when the JIT does inlining automatically, while I want explicit inlining, even as part of a public API.

One final note: Please don't preach me that "objects are cheap". I have been doing Java for 10 years and been in charge the JVM profiling in my team for at least the last 6 years, so I painfully know what objects costs.

Answer (score 4):

What you're talking about sounds a lot like [value types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_type) - types that should be treated as "direct" values instead of as objects (accessed through references), just like the primitive types.

Java does not have user-definable value types, and will most likely not get those in a new version anytime soon (maybe in Java 9 or even later). As far as I know, the JVM or JIT also does not automatically treat your objects as value types ("full class inlining").

Note that C# does have [user-definable value types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx).

However, the inlining of methods can already make your code quite efficient. Consider this:

```
class MyValue {
    private int value;

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

The getter and setter method will be inlined by the JVM when you call them, so calling those methods is just as efficient as directly accessing the `value` member variable of the class. An instance of `MyValue` will however take up more memory than an `int`, because Java objects have some unavoidable overhead (for example, you can synchronize on any object in Java, so each object has to have a lock associated with it - this lock is part of the state of the object).

Because Java lacks value types, it's not possible to create an array of objects that are guaranteed to be laid out consecutively in memory. An array with an element type that is a non-primitive type is really an array of references to objects, and the objects that these references point to can in principle be scattered all across the heap. That's not good for performance for certain operations (for example, if you iterate through the array, the CPU's cache works most efficiently if the memory access pattern is predictable - it will be less efficient if the objects are scattered in random places).

About objects being cheap: one optimization in recent JDKs is [escape analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_performance#Escape_analysis_and_lock_coarsening), which will cause temporary objects local to a method to be allocated on the stack instead of the heap, so that freeing the allocated memory is essentially free (the garbage collector doesn't have to deal with the object).

Comment: Yes, user-definable value types is exactly what I want. While what you say about escape analysis sounds promising, the link does not mention "stack allocation"; in fact, the word stack does not even appear on that page. If you have a link that actually confirms your claim, I would very much like to see it.

Comment: @Sebastien see [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp09275/index.html) by Brian Goetz, also [this](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue179.html) might be interesting.